# URL decode a column in table

Tags: oracle, urldecode

How can I url decode a value in Oracle?

I have a URL encoded string stored in oracle DB table. I want to url_encode it while selecting the results. Any quick way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 7):

Oracle provides [utl_url](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_url.htm) package containing two functions [escape()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10577/u_url.htm#i996850) and [unescape()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10577/u_url.htm#i996904)  which allow you encode and decode `url`s.  To decode an encoded url string `http://www.%24-%26-%3C-%3E-%3F`, for example, we can do the following:

```
SQL> select utl_url.unescape('http://www.%24-%26-%3C-%3E-%3F') as res
  2   from dual
  3  ;
```

Result:

```
RES
---------------------
http://www.$-&-<->-?
```

Note. If you need to use `escape()` function, you wont be able to use it in a `select` statement directly, because the second parameter of the function is of Boolean datatype. You will need to write a wrapper function.

```
SQL> create or replace function url_encode(p_url in varchar2)
  2  return varchar2
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    return utl_url.escape(p_url, true);
  6  end;
  7  /
Function created

SQL> 
SQL> select Url_encode('http://www.$-&-<->-?') as res
  2   from dual
  3  ;
```

Result:

```
RES
-------------------------------------
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.%24-%26-%3C-%3E-%3F
```

Comment: doesn't decode unicode like Thai or Benghazi  `select utl_url. unescape('%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%94%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%A5%E0%B9%87%E0%B8%81-%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%AA%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%99%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%99%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%87') as res     from dual;` gives `à¸à¸¥à¸²à¸à¹à¸¥à¹à¸-à¸­à¸´à¸ªà¸²à¸à¸à¸±à¸à¹à¸­à¸`

Comment: `select utl_url. unescape('%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%94%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%A5%E0%B9%87%E0%B8%81-%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%AA%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%99%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%99%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%87', 'UTF-8') as res     from dual`
did the trick

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

utl_url.unescape(replace('*your text here*', '+', ' '),'UTF-8')